# Closing issue for the jquery dialogbox load the other page

Tags: jquery

I used the code below to load the internal page on the jQuery dailogbox, but when I click Cancel button on the internal page. It remain the dialog box title bar on the screen. How can I complete get away the dialog box.

```
$("#dialogBox").load('http://internalpage.aspx').dialog({
  title: $(this).attr("data-dialog-title"),
  close: function() { $(this).remove() },
  modal: true

})
```

There is the code I close the dialog

```
$('#dialog-box').dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  resizable: true,     
  title: name,
  modal: true
});

$('#dialog-box').dialog('close');
```

Comment: Have you tried changing -  close: function() { $(this).remove() },  -  To -- close: function() { $(this).close() },

Comment: Are you using a jQuery-ui dialog box or some other plugin?

Comment: @GreggDuncan, yes I tried this before, it has an error.

Comment: @Franco, yes I used it